# unset description in user_profile_form

Tags: users

I try to remove descriptions of language, files (avatar) and timezone in user profile form:

```
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    unset($form['account']['mail']['#description']);
    unset($form['account']['pass']['#description']);
    unset($form['account']['language']['#description']);
    unset($form['account']['files']['#description']);
    unset($form['account']['timezone']['#description']);
   }
}
```

This code removes mail and password descriptions but it does not removes language, files and timezone descriptions.

Please, what is wrong with this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to increase weight of your custom module for removing description of `timezone field`. Your code should be like below:

```
if($form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
  unset($form['account']['mail']['#description']);
  unset($form['account']['pass']['#description']);
  unset($form['locale']['language']['#description']);
  unset($form['picture']['picture_delete']['#description']);
  unset($form['picture']['picture_upload']['#description']);
  unset($form['timezone']['timezone']['#description']);
}
```

Comment: Manish, thank you! But the image description was not removed:  
'Your virtual face or picture. Pictures larger than 1024x1024 pixels will be scaled down.'

Comment: `unset($form['picture']['picture_upload']['#description']);` it worked for me. Try to clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try form after build.

```
if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
   $form['#after_build'][] = 'my_module_user_profile_form_after_build';

   }
}

function my_module_user_profile_form_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  unset($element['timezone']['timezone']['#description']); 
}
```

Similarly try for language and file fields. In $element you will find language and file elements. Clear cache the cache.

Comment: Thank you! Why to make it too difficult? One person has sayed me that 'path' is incorrect: unset($form['account']['language']['#description']); So i need to make this path correct. Can you tell me pls what is correct path? Thank you!

Comment: I think path in the sense, $form['account'] may not have ['language'], so it is not working. You can use devel module for debugging. dpm($form) will give path of each field.

Comment: have you found the solution.

Comment: Here is simple solution: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/216754/67723 but file description was not removed.